# I have an Apex Code , it has to be optimized with less no of lines . ? Ignore System.debugs , and Comments

Tags: apex

```
/***
 *Name             : orchestrationProcessInserter
 *Description      : Created for inserting orchestration process and to order update.
 **/
public class OrchestrationProcessInserter 
{
    /***
     *Name             : insertorchestrationProcess.method
     *Description      : below method is updationg the order's data
     ***/

    public void insertorchestrationProcess(List <csordm__Order__c> newOrderList,Boolean isBefore,Boolean isAfter) {
    System.debug('newOrderList'+newOrderList);
    System.debug('newOrderList size'+newOrderList.size());
    System.debug('entered into InsertorchestrationProcess Method');
     Boolean byPassUser = false;
        for(Bypass_Orchestration_Process__c byPassProcessRecord : Bypass_Orchestration_Process__c.getAll().values()) {
        if(UserInfo.getUserName() == byPassProcessRecord.User_Name__c && byPassProcessRecord.Is_Bypass__c) {
            byPassUser = true;
            break;
            }
            }
        Boolean byPassViznetUser = false;
        for(Bypass_Orchestration_Process_for_Viznet__c byPassOrchForViznet : Bypass_Orchestration_Process_for_Viznet__c.getAll().values()) {
        if(UserInfo.getuserId() == byPassOrchForViznet.User_ID__c && byPassOrchForViznet.Is_Bypass__c) 
            {
            byPassViznetUser = true;
            break;
            }
            } 

        if (isBefore && !byPassViznetUser) {
            set<Id> relatedOpportunityId = new Set <Id> ();
            set<Id> relatedBundleId = new Set <Id> ();
            for (csordm__Order__c orderRecord : newOrderList) {
                relatedOpportunityId.add(orderRecord.csordm__Opportunity__c);
                relatedBundleId.add(orderRecord.csordm__Product_Bundle__c);
            }            
            Set<Id> relatedProductConfigSet = new Set<Id>(); 
            Integer totalSites = 0;
            Map<Id,String> relatedProductConfigWithValueMap = new Map<Id,String>();
            for(cscfga__Product_Configuration__c confData : [SELECT Id, Name,Primary__c ,VariantName__c,Bsse_Cloned_Configuration__c , cscfga__Parent_Configuration__c, cscfga__Product_Bundle__c, cscfga__Product_Definition__r.Name,Related_Product_Configuration__c,ToBeDeleted__c FROM cscfga__Product_Configuration__c   WHERE cscfga__Product_bundle__c In : relatedBundleId]) 
            {
                if (confData.VariantName__c == 'Equipment Sales' &&  confData.Bsse_Cloned_Configuration__c == 'NO') {
                    relatedProductConfigSet.add(confData.Related_Product_Configuration__c);
                    relatedProductConfigWithValueMap.put(confData.Related_Product_Configuration__c,'Yes');
                }
                if(confData.VariantName__c == 'Site End Point' && confData.ToBeDeleted__c == true) {
                    ++totalSites;
                }
            }
            Integer noOfCPE = relatedProductConfigSet.size();
            for(csordm__Order__c orderRecord : newOrderList) {
                orderRecord.Total_Equip_Proff_Site_Added__c = String.valueof(noOfCPE);
                orderRecord.Equipment_Sales_Added__c=relatedProductConfigWithValueMap.get(orderRecord.csordm__Product_Configuration__c);
                orderRecord.BSSE_Total_Site_Tobe_Deleted__c = totalSites;
                system.debug('OrderId'+orderRecord.Id+orderRecord.Equipment_Sales_Added__c);
            }
        }
        if(isAfter && !byPassUser && !byPassViznetUser)
         { 
            System.debug('After Insert is Called');

        Map<string,Id> processTemplateNameIdMap = new Map<string,Id> ();
        Set<Id> oppId = new Set<Id> ();
        for(csordm__Order__c oppIdSet: newOrderList)
        {
            oppId.add(oppIdSet.csordm__Opportunity__c);
        }
        List<Opportunity> oppData = [Select Opportunity_Record_Name__c,migration_status__c,Sub_Type__c,Type,RecordTypeId,Bundle_Name__c,Bundled_Order_Type_One__c,Bundled_Order_Type_Two__c,Bundled_Order_Type_Three__c,Bundled_Order_Type_Five__c,Bundled_Order_Type_Four__c,Bundled_Product_One__c,Bundled_Product_Two__c,Parent_Opportunity__r.Type,Bundled_Product_Three__c,Bundled_Product_Four__c,Bundled_Product_Five__c,Bundled_Sub_Order_Type_One__c,Bundled_Sub_Order_Type_Two__c,Bundled_Sub_Order_type_Three__c,Bundled_Sub_Order_type_Four__c,Bundled_Sub_Order_Type_Five__c from Opportunity where Id in : oppId];
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity opp : oppData) {
            oppMap.put(opp.id, opp);
        }

            for(CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process_Template__c templateData : [select Id,Name from CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process_Template__c]) {
                processTemplateNameIdMap.put(templateData.Name , templateData.Id);
            }            
            List<CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process__c> processList = new List<CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process__c>();
            Map<String,OrchestrationProcessOrderMapping__c>  orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey = new Map<String,OrchestrationProcessOrderMapping__c>();
           System.debug('1-Test');
            for(OrchestrationProcessOrderMapping__c processMappingRecord : [SELECT Bsse_Cloned_Configuration__c,Equipment_Sales_Added__c,Id,Is_Changed__c,Name,Opportunity_Sub_Type__c,Opportunity_Type__c,Oppty_Record_Name__c,Order_Category__c,Order_Product_Family__c,Primary_Order_Variant_Name__c,Process_Name__c,Process_Template_Name__c,Product_Name__c,Site_Room_Type__c,ToBeDeleted__c FROM OrchestrationProcessOrderMapping__c]) 
            {
                System.debug('2-Test');
                String key = '';
                if(processMappingRecord.Order_Product_Family__c != null && processMappingRecord.Order_Product_Family__c !='')
                key = processMappingRecord.Order_Product_Family__c;
                if(processMappingRecord.Oppty_Record_Name__c != null && processMappingRecord.Oppty_Record_Name__c !='')              
                key +='_'+processMappingRecord.Oppty_Record_Name__c ;
                if(processMappingRecord.Product_Name__c != null && processMappingRecord.Product_Name__c != '')
                key+= '_'+processMappingRecord.Product_Name__c ;
                if(processMappingRecord.Opportunity_Type__c!= null && processMappingRecord.Opportunity_Type__c!= '')
                key+='_'+processMappingRecord.Opportunity_Type__c ;
                if(processMappingRecord.Opportunity_Sub_Type__c!= null && processMappingRecord.Opportunity_Sub_Type__c!='')
                key+='_'+processMappingRecord.Opportunity_Sub_Type__c; 
                if(processMappingRecord.Order_Product_Family__c == 'InstaCC Global' || processMappingRecord.Order_Product_Family__c == 'Dedicated Collaboration Solutions' || processMappingRecord.Order_Product_Family__c == 'InstaCC' || processMappingRecord.Order_Product_Family__c == 'Skype for Business')               
                key+='_'+processMappingRecord.Is_Changed__c;
                if(processMappingRecord.Order_Product_Family__c == 'Telepresence')
                {
                if(processMappingRecord.Order_Category__c!= null && processMappingRecord.Order_Category__c!= '')                
                //key+='_'+processMappingRecord.Order_Category__c;                                 
                key+='_'+processMappingRecord.Site_Room_Type__c;
                key+='_'+processMappingRecord.Equipment_Sales_Added__c;
                key+='_'+processMappingRecord.Primary_Order_Variant_Name__c;
                key+='_'+processMappingRecord.ToBeDeleted__c;
                key+='_'+processMappingRecord.Bsse_Cloned_Configuration__c;
                }
                System.debug('key checkin>>'+key);

                orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.put(key,processMappingRecord);

            }

            System.debug('orderData123>>'+newOrderList.size());            
            for(csordm__Order__c orderData : newOrderList) {
                System.debug('orderData csordm__Order_Category__c '+orderData.csordm__Order_Category__c+'orderData'+orderData.Id);
                String Key1  = '';
                String Key2  = '';          
                String migrationStatus = oppMap.get(orderData.csordm__opportunity__c).migration_status__c;
                if(migrationStatus == null || migrationStatus.equalsIgnoreCase('In Progress') == false)
                {
                //Key1 START
                if(orderData.Product_Family__c != null && orderData.Product_Family__c !='')
                key1 = orderData.Product_Family__c;
                if(orderData.Opportunity_Record_Type__c != null && orderData.Opportunity_Record_Type__c != '')              
                key1 +='_'+orderData.Opportunity_Record_Type__c;
                if(orderData.Product_Variant_Name__c !=null && orderData.Product_Variant_Name__c !='')
                key1+= '_'+orderData.Product_Variant_Name__c;
                if(orderData.Opportunity_Type__c != null && orderData.Opportunity_Type__c != '')
                key1+='_'+orderData.Opportunity_Type__c;
                if(orderData.Opportunity_Sub_Type__c != null && orderData.Opportunity_Sub_Type__c !='')
                key1+='_'+orderData.Opportunity_Sub_Type__c;                              
                if(orderData.Product_Family__c == 'InstaCC Global' || orderData.Product_Family__c == 'Dedicated Collaboration Solutions' || orderData.Product_Family__c == 'InstaCC' || orderData.Product_Family__c == 'Skype for Business')
                key1 +='_'+orderData.Is_Changed__c;
                if(orderData.Product_Family__c == 'Telepresence')
                {                
                key1 +='_'+orderData.Site_Room_Type__c;
                key1 +='_'+orderData.Equipment_Sales_Added__c;
                key1+='_'+orderData.Primary_Order_Variant_Name__c;
                key1 +='_'+orderData.csordm__Product_Configuration__r.ToBeDeleted__c;
                key1 +='_'+orderData.csordm__Product_Configuration__r.Bsse_Cloned_Configuration__c;
                }
               //key1 END 
                If(orderData.Opportunity_Type__c == 'Currency/Billing Entity/Customer Entity')
                {
                    key2 = '_'+orderData.Opportunity_Type__c;
                }
                else
                {
                 if(orderData.Product_Family__c != null && orderData.Product_Family__c !='')
                key2 = orderData.Product_Family__c;
                if(orderData.Opportunity_Record_Type__c != null && orderData.Opportunity_Record_Type__c != '')              
                key2 +='_'+orderData.Opportunity_Record_Type__c;
                if(orderData.Product_Variant_Name__c !=null && orderData.Product_Variant_Name__c !='')
                key2+= '_'+orderData.Product_Variant_Name__c;
                if(orderData.Opportunity_Type__c != null && orderData.Opportunity_Type__c != '')
                key2+='_'+orderData.Opportunity_Type__c;      
                if(orderData.Product_Family__c == 'InstaCC Global' || orderData.Product_Family__c == 'Dedicated Collaboration Solutions' || orderData.Product_Family__c == 'InstaCC' || orderData.Product_Family__c == 'Skype for Business')                               
                key2 +='_'+orderData.Is_Changed__c;
                if(orderData.Product_Family__c == 'Telepresence')
                {                
                key2 +='_'+orderData.Site_Room_Type__c;
                key2 +='_'+orderData.Equipment_Sales_Added__c;
                key2+='_'+orderData.Primary_Order_Variant_Name__c;
                key2 +='_'+orderData.csordm__Product_Configuration__r.ToBeDeleted__c;
                key2 +='_'+orderData.csordm__Product_Configuration__r.Bsse_Cloned_Configuration__c;
                }
                }


                  System.debug('key1 ccheckin>>'+Key1+'**'+orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.containsKey(Key1));
                  System.debug('Key2 ccheckin>>'+Key2+'**'+orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.containsKey(Key2));      

                   try{  
                   if(orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey != null)
                   if((orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.containsKey(Key1)  || orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.containsKey(Key2)))
                   {

                   System.debug('Testing whether key is satisfying the condition or not  >>>'+orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.get(Key1));
                   System.debug('Testing whether key is satisfying the condition or not  >>>'+orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.get(Key2));

                       CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process__c newProcess = new CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process__c();   
                       if(orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.containsKey(Key1))
                       {      
                       System.debug('Key1');           
                       newProcess.CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process_Template__c =  processTemplateNameIdMap.get(orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.get(Key1).Process_Template_Name__c);                      
                       newProcess.Name = orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.get(Key1).Process_Name__c; 
                       System.debug('Key1'+newProcess.Name); 
                       }
                       else
                       {
                       newProcess.CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process_Template__c =  processTemplateNameIdMap.get(orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.get(Key2).Process_Template_Name__c);                      
                       newProcess.Name = orchestrationProcessOrderMapwithKey.get(Key2).Process_Name__c; 
                        System.debug('Key2'+newProcess.Name); 
                       }                          
                       newProcess.CSPOFA__Process_Type__c = 'New Provide';
                       newProcess.csordm__Order__c = orderData.Id;
                       system.debug('Process Check@@'+newProcess.csordm__Order__c);
                       processList.add(newProcess);

                   }
                   }
                   Catch(Exception e)
                   {

                   }
                }   
            }       
            if(processList != null && !processList.isEmpty()) 
            {
                insert processList;
                System.debug('PROCESS ATTACHED - END');
            }
        }
        // process for TP Migration
    if(isAfter && byPassUser && !byPassViznetUser)
    {
        Map<string,Id> processTemplateNameIdMap2 = new Map<string,Id> ();
         for(CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process_Template__c templateData : [select Id,Name from CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process_Template__c])
            {
                processTemplateNameIdMap2.put(templateData.Name , templateData.Id);
            }
                List<CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process__c> processList2= new List<CSPOFA__Orchestration_Process__c>();
        for(csordm__Order__c orderData : newOrderList)
        {    
            String prdName1 = orderData.Product_Variant_Name__c;
            String primProductName = orderData.Primary_Order_Variant_Name__c;
            String ProductFamily = orderData.Product_Family__c;
            if(ProductFamily == '' || ProductFamily == null) {
                processList2.add(orderUtil.addToProcessList(processTemplateNameIdMap2.get('TP Migration Process'), 'TP Migration Process', orderData.Id));               
            }
            else
            { // this block is for attaching process to MHS
                processList2.add(orderUtil.addToProcessList(processTemplateNameIdMap2.get('TP Provisioning Process'), 'TP Provisioning Process', orderData.Id));

            }
        }
        if(processList2 != null && !processList2.isEmpty())
            insert processList2;       
    } 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start by doing some research such as reading:

- https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-method
- https://refactoring.guru/extract-method

and then apply what you learn.

A key benefit of moving code out of triggers is to be able to use techniques like breaking the work up into multiple well-named methods so its clearer what the code does and so that repeated logic can be implemented once only in a method that is called multiple times.